# Which format is used for distribution of signed certificates by real CA

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I am working on [CA implementation](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/certificate_authority) on rails (quite raw), using recipes from OpenSSL cookbook by Ivan Ristić and have stumbled

1. Applicant (or developer, or server) have my CA root certificate
2. He made csr request
3. [my CA sing it with intermediate `subca` certificate](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/certificate_authority/blob/master/app/commands/create_from_csr.rb)
4. How to provide certificate to applicant with all chain that he will use for verification? How this made by real CA? Or even should I provide all chain or applicant must derive `subca.crt` url from `authorityInfoAccess` extension and upload it by himself (which lies in `public` dir)?

Comment: It depends on the CA but often they are provided in multiple ways suitable for easy installation with the most common servers. This often includes separate PEM files for lead and chain certificates, a single PEM file with lead and chain and pkcs#7 files.

Comment: removed tag *rails* and *openssl* since you ask how common CA provide the certificate which is unrelated to your current implementation using openssl and rails. Added tags *certificates* and *certificate-authority* instead.

Comment: I have decided to use pkcs7 (want to investigate) but this [seems to be slightly broken](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/120)

Comment: Steffen, do you know, are certificates, distributed by CA in pkcs7 signed or encrypted or not? If so, by which certificate they must be signed?

Comment: I don't know but I doubt it because there would be no reason for it: They are intended for the public anyway so there is no need for encryption. And each certificate is already signed by the certificate upper in the chain and ultimately by the root CA so there is no need for additional signatures.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, hi, can you help me, please, I am stuck with [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/154842/cant-request-ocsp-status-with-chain-of-certificates) question and can't find valid command about 3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different CA does this differently.

One CA I've used out as a downloadable zip file containing your certificate and the intermediate certificate in various formats. Others provide a preconcatenated certificate and intermediate certificates as a single pem file. Some just points you to another page where you can download the intermediate certificates.

Personally, I find downloading them as a single downloadable zip is the easiest, and most convenient way to receive certificates.

Recently, some CA like Let's Encrypt also provide automated issuance. In this manner, you install an [acme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Certificate_Management_Environment) script on your server, and then that script automatically detects your web server, orders a certificate, automatically configure your webserver to do domain validation, downloads the signed certificate in the right format for your particular server, and automatically installs the certificate for you on the web server. The script can also be installed as a cronjob that automatically renews the certificate when it is close to expiry. If you're just configuring a domain validated certificate, this can be the most convenient for users, but it's also the most difficult to implement for CAs.

Comment: Suppose I have a server and obtained my server lead certificate and it's chain by whatever way that you have described. How works https? Server must provide lead certificate and it's chain, in what format? How?

Comment: How server know where obtain it's certificate chain?

Comment: I have found this: for example on Apache certificate chain is configured by `SSLCertificateChainFile chain.pem`