# Can't request ocsp status with chain of certificates

Tags: openssl, ocsp

I have deployed basic ocsp server from `OpenSSl Cookbook` by Ivan Ristic page 44 with following command

```
$ openssl ocsp -port 9080 -index db/index -rsigner root-ocsp.crt -rkey private/root-ocsp.key -CA root-ca.crt -text
```

Certs have following chain `root-ca -> root-ocsp` and `root-ca -> sub-ca -> server` and I want to request status of `server.crt`.

```
$ openssl ocsp -issuer root-ca.crt -issuer sub-ca.crt  -CAfile root-ocsp.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080
Response Verify Failure
139779327862424:error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:ocsp_vfy.c:138:Verify error:unable to get localissuer certificate
server.crt: unknown
        This Update: Mar 24 19:44:15 2017 GMT

$ openssl ocsp -issuer root-ca.crt -issuer sub-ca.crt  -CAfile root-ca.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080
Response Verify Failure
140137564870296:error:27069070:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted:ocsp_vfy.c:166:
server.crt: unknown
        This Update: Mar 24 19:51:42 2017 GMT

$ openssl ocsp -issuer sub-ca.crt -issuer root-ca.crt  -CAfile root-ocsp.crt -verify_other root-ca.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080
Response Verify Failure
140252372211352:error:27069065:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:certificate verify error:ocsp_vfy.c:138:Verify error:self signed certificate in certificate chain
server.crt: unknown
        This Update: Mar 24 19:53:15 2017 GMT

 $ openssl ocsp -issuer sub-ca.crt -issuer root-ca.crt -CAfile root-ca.crt -verify_other root-ocsp.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080
Response Verify Failure
140563322316440:error:27069070:OCSP routines:OCSP_basic_verify:root ca not trusted:ocsp_vfy.c:166:
server.crt: unknown
        This Update: Mar 24 19:54:16 2017 GMT
```

What I am doing wrong?

```
$ ll
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 2 bjorn users     4096 Mar 24 11:19 certs
drwxr-xr-x 2 bjorn users     4096 Mar 24 11:19 db
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn wireshark 3160 Mar 19 13:08 ocsp_recording.pcapng
drwxr-xr-x 2 bjorn users     4096 Mar 24 10:56 private
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     2542 Mar 24 11:03 root-ca.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      934 Mar 17 21:50 root-ca.crl
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     6876 Mar 17 21:39 root-ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     1732 Mar 16 14:29 root-ca.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     5747 Mar 19 10:09 root-ocsp.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      948 Mar 17 22:07 root-ocsp.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     5103 Mar 24 11:19 server.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      980 Mar 24 11:03 server.csr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     2436 Mar 16 14:11 sub-ca.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users     6682 Mar 17 22:03 sub-ca.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bjorn users      928 Mar 17 21:58 sub-ca.csr
```

[Whole project zip](http://dropmefiles.com/tB7VU) (everywhere password is `pass`)

Comment: Have you looked at EJBCA? Easier to work with than OpenSSL.

Comment: @KirillSinitski, hah, no, and I cant because [CA on Openssl is my diploma](https://github.com/BjornMelgaard/certificate_authority), I must make this on Openssl

Comment: and I want it to be compatible with openssl cli

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the following setup:

- server.crt is issued by sub-ca.crt, sub-ca.crt is issued by root-ca.crt
- OCSP response is signed by root-ocsp.crt which was issued by root-ca.crt

The process to validate a OCSP response is described in [RFC 2560 section 4.2.2.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2560.txt). (now obsoleted by [RFC 6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960#section-4.2.2.2)) In short the OCSP response must be

- either signed by the issuer of the certificate in question, i.e. signed by sub-ca.crt in your case.
- or signed by a designated responder. This responder must have an extended key usage of OCSPSigning **and must be issued by the issuer of the certificate in question**. This means the responders certificate must be signed by sub-ca.crt.

You are trying to use the designated responder. Your responder has the correct extended key usage. **But the responder is issued by root-ca.crt whereas the certificate in question is issued by sub-ca.crt.** This conflicts with the requirement that the issuer of the responder certificate must be the issuer of the queried certificate and thus the validation fails.

Comment: 1 `openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -subj "/C=GB/O=Example/CN=OCSP Subca Responder" -keyout private/subca-ocsp.key -out subca-ocsp.csr` 2. `openssl ca -config sub-ca.conf -in subca-ocsp.csr -out subca-ocsp.crt -extensions ocsp_ext -days 30` 3. `openssl ocsp -port 9080 -index db/index -rsigner subca-ocsp.crt -rkey private/subca-ocsp.key -CA sub-ca.crt -text`

Comment: 4 and there I have failed: `openssl ocsp -issuer sub-ca.crt -CAfile sub-ca.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080` respond with status good but error `unable to get issuer certificate`, `openssl ocsp -issuer sub-ca.crt -issuer root-ca.crt -CAfile sub-ca.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080` respond with status unknown and same error

Comment: As I have understood - extension have no matter, and as wiki says `-issuer` parameter can be used multiple times

Comment: @BjornMelgaard:  `-CAfile sub-ca.crt` - CAfile behaves different then you might think. This just adds sub-ca.crt to the list of CAs it takes into account. It still wants to have a root certificate. Try with `-CAfile  sub-and-root.crt` with `cat sub-ca.crt root-ca.crt > sub-and-root.crt` so that it has both the chain certificate and the root certificate. Works for me at least.

Comment: `openssl ocsp -issuer sub-ca.crt -CAfile sub-and-root.crt -cert server.crt -url http://127.0.0.1:9080` I will tell about you to my children (if I ever have one)

Comment: [Same on ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43015883/3574379)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much of use to add to Steffen's answer, but I found two minor additional points which could be helpful too:

1) According to the man pages for openssl and OCSP,  [the -issuer parameter must be in pem format, not .crt.](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ocsp.html)

2) There is a command option -text which should give a more verbose output

Based on the above, I would think that a better command should look something like this, you will need to add server.pem though, as I can't see it in the files provided:

`openssl ocsp -issuer serverchain.pem -cert server.pem -text -url http://127.0.0.1:9080`

Comment: There is no CRT format. There is PEM, DER ... . `.crt` is just the extension of the file and could be used for any kind of format. In this specific case the `*.crt` files contain the certificate as PEM.